# Email composer does not launch the mobile mail app (gmail)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have followed this tutorial, 
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/send-email-android-ios-ionicframework/

But still gives me the choice to choose an app for sharing. But i love that the application  launches Gmail app  directly.Thanks

Comment: If its working fine can you please accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin- https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer

I have tried it in one of my project and it works fine.
On Android the app can be specified by either an alias or its package name. The alias gmail is available by default.
To open gmail app-

```
// Add app alias
cordova.plugins.email.addAlias('gmail', 'com.google.android.gm');

// Specify app by name or alias
cordova.plugins.email.open({
    app: 'gmail',
    subject: 'Sent from Gmail'
})
```

*Many users will not have Gmail app on their phones, so from compatibility perspective better approach will be to let user choose email composer app.*